# Помогите извлечь файлы из реестра с#

Tags: c#, автозагрузка, автозапуск

http://www.cyberforum.ru/windows-forms/thread1980085.html#taglist
НЕ могу извлечь файлы из  HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run\ 
выводит файл но в папке Run его нет

---

Подробное условие:
Нужно извлечь файлы автозагрузки отсюда 
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run\
но вместо видимых мною файлов выводит не эти файлы а какой-то другой, не пойму откуда, в диспетчере задаx -> этот файл есть как и те что в не отображаются в моей программе из папки Run 
вот файл

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

вот реестр

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
    RegistryKey current_user,local_machine;

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        current_user = Registry.CurrentUser.CreateSubKey(
          "SOFTWARE\\Microsoft\\Windows\\CurrentVersion\\Run\");
        foreach (string valueName in current_user.GetValueNames())
        {
            listBox1.Items.Add(valueName);
        }
        local_machine = Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey(
          "SOFTWARE\\Microsoft\\Windows\\CurrentVersion\\Run\",true);
        foreach (string valueName in local_machine.GetValueNames())
        {
            listBox1.Items.Add(valueName);
        }
    }


    private void button_add_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        OpenFileDialog OPF = new OpenFileDialog();
        OPF.Multiselect = true;
        OPF.ShowDialog();
        if (OPF.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            foreach (string file in OPF.FileNames)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(file);
                MessageBox.Show(Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(OPF.FileName));

            }
        }
        string file_name = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(OPF.FileName);
        string file_path = OPF.FileName;

        current_user.SetValue(file_name, file_path);
        // current_user.Close();
        listBox1.Items.Insert(1,file_name);
    }

    private void button_delete_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string file_name = listBox1.SelectedItem.ToString();

        current_user.DeleteValue(file_name, false);
        // current_user.Close();
        listBox1.Items.Remove(file_name);
    }
}
```

---

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

как видите эти фалйы видно а из LOCAL_MACHINE не могу вывести

в диспечтере все есть

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Стоит поместить **всё** условие вопроса в вопрос, а не располагать ссылки на сторонние ресурсы

Comment: не все изображения могу прикрепить на этом сайте

Comment: почему? это же не запрещено) как минимум можешь их (картинки) поместить в виде ссылок и внести уточнение, что из-за малой репутации - невозможно прикрепить целиком, а проверяющие уже помогут подправить....... для того, чтобы внести правку в вопрос, достаточно нажать "Править"))

Comment: кроме описанного в ответе, попробуйте запустить что-то типа CCleaner и посмотреть что он выводит в списке автозапуска. У меня оно всегда совпадает с реестром. А вот список задач в диспетчере всегда больше чем список автозапуска, т.к. не все что автоматически запускается есть в автозапуске, но об этом я уже написал в ответе\

Answer (score 4):

**Реестр**

1. Если какая-то программа использует настройки реестра, то информация может (но не обязана) быть в реестре.
2. Если в реестре (любой ветке) есть запись о программе, это не означает, что программа существует и корректно установлена на компьютере.
3. Реестр можно использовать как доверенный справочник по системным настройкам, т.к. это отслеживает сама система, но информацию о программах, которые не являются частью Windows нужно проверять, она вполне может быть неактуальной.
4. В реестре бывают ошибки, которые не мешают явно работе системы, но могут приводить к ошибкам в различных сторонних программах, если они используют значения реестра без проверки их актуальности и корректности.
5. Существует 100500 причин по которым в реестре появляются невалидные ключи, от кривого деинсталлятора и/или апдейтера, до багов самой системы.
6. Некоторые ветви реестра получаются путем объединения пользовательской и системной ветвей, иногда результат объединения может содержать "сюрпризы" разной степени "приятности".
7. Интересующая вас ветка `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run\` содержит только системные записи о запускаемых программах, для текущего активного пользователя нужно искать записи в  `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run\`. Суммарная информация из этих двух веток будет соответствовать полному списку автозапуска для текущего активного пользователя.

**Диспетчер задач**

1. Диспетчер задач может отображать специально заданные для этого имена программ, вместо имен файлов, с помощью которых эти программы запущены.
2. Диспетчер задач показывает не всегда все, что реально запущено, от него вполне можно скрыть отдельные процессы, но все что отображает диспетчер реально запущено в момент просмотра.
3. В штатном диспетчере можно включить отображение реальных путей к исполняемым файлам для видимых процессов, но это нужно делать специально, по-умолчанию эта опция отключена. Не знаю какая версия Windows у вас используется, но искать нужно настройки отображаемых столбцов (ориентировочно в меню "Вид" => "Выбрать столбцы"), вам нужен столбец "Путь к образу".

**Планировщик задач Windows**

Некоторые программы используют для автозапуска системный планировщик задач (апдейтер хрома например), их, разумеется, нет в этих ветках реестра, хотя есть подозрение, что сами задачи все таки хранятся в реестре, но где именно я не знаю, не копал.

**Папка "Автозагрузка" (StartUp)**

Есть специальные папки: общая и индивидуальные для каждого пользователя

```
C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup
C:\Users\UserName\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup
```

(пути к данным папкам могут отличаться, в зависимости от локальных настроек системы и профиля пользователя)

В этих папках могут быть ярлыки для автоматического запуска программ, при входе пользователя в систему.

Также, некоторые программы, могут быть запущены с помощью других программ. Информацию по этим программам так просто получить не удастся, придется экспериментировать и изучать кто, что и зачем запускает. Тоже касается системных процессов, которые запускаются не зависимо от желания и настроек пользователя.

Если остались вопросы - оставьте комментарий или внесите уточнение в вопрос.